# Angular 4 - completely route to new component

Tags: angular

I am using [routerLink](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) to navigate from current `component` to new `component`

```
<div class="form-list-container">
<h3>Contact Form</h3>
<button md-raised-button routerLink="/add-form" 
routerLinkActive="active">Add New</button>

<all-forms></all-forms>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

After clicking `Add New` button it renders `/add-form` router component view to

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

along with all other HTML elements.

**EDIT**

For routing i have following code -

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'home',   component: AppComponent },
{ path: 'add-form',  component: AddFormViewComponent },
]
```

When user click on `Add New` button, i want the user to move on `AddFormViewComponent` view rather then adding `AddFormViewComponent` view within current `component`.

Comment: Then put all the other HTML inside the view of the current component.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
<div class="form-list-container">
 <h3>Contact Form</h3>
 <button md-raised-button routerLink="/add-form" 
  routerLinkActive="active">Add New</button>

 <all-forms></all-forms>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood what you want to do, you need to create two routes.

I use to create a routing module. app-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'home',   component: Component1 },
    { path: 'add-form',   component: Component2 }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

In the app.module.ts, add the routing module import :

```
imports: [
    ...,
    AppRoutingModule ]
```

The app.component.html can contain only one line :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The component1.component.html :

```
<div class="form-list-container">
<h3>Contact Form</h3>
<button md-raised-button routerLink="/add-form" 
routerLinkActive="active">Add New</button>

<all-forms></all-forms>

</div>
```

The component2.component.html should not be changed.